# Want to reduce nested if else statement to reduce the cognitive complexity?

Tags: javascript

//I have a function that returns the search result based on the input user put in the search //field. The code is build using a nested if-else statement which in result adding the cognitive //complexity of the code. I want to reduce the code complexity by reducing the if-else //statements.
//here is my code

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
  });
  function myFunction() {
    $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
      var  i;
      var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
      var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      var table = document.getElementById("tabledisplay");
      var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      var e = document.getElementById("searchtype");
      var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        if (strUser == 'Date') {
          td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
          if (td) {
          var txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
        else if (strUser == 'City') {
          td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
          if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
        else if (strUser == 'State') {
          td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
          if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
        else if (strUser == 'Inspection Number') {
          td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[5];
          if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an object to look up the string index

```
const indexes = {
  Date: 1,
  City: 2,
  State: 3,
  'Inspection Number': 5
}

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
  });
  function myFunction() {
    $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
      var  i;
      var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
      var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      var table = document.getElementById("tabledisplay");
      var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      var e = document.getElementById("searchtype");
      var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        if (strUser in indexes) {
          index = indexes[strUser]
          td = tr[index].getElementsByTagName("td")[index];
          if (td) {
          var txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Comment: I think the index is not getting proper value

Answer (score 1):

Considering the only difference between `if(`-blocks is the line:

```
 td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
```

You may simply have an object, like:

```
const fields = {Date: 1, City: 2, State: 3..
```

Then use that block just once, passing `strUser` as a key name:

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[fields[strUser}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code repeated. You could write another function with I think two parameters to clean this up.

As far as the if/else statements, for the one liner if/else blocks you can leverage ternaries. For the top level if/else statements you could use a switch statement.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    myFunction();
  });

  function tdFunc(td = false, index, filter) {
    if (!td) return false;

    let txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
    txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ?
        tr[index].style.display = "" :
        tr[index].style.display = "none";
  }

  function myFunction() {
    $("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
      var i;
      var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
      var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      var table = document.getElementById("tabledisplay");
      var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      var e = document.getElementById("searchtype");
      var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

      Array.from(tr).forEach((el, i) => {

        switch(strUser) {
            case 'Date':
                tdFunc(
                    tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1], 
                    i,
                    filter
                );
                break;
            case 'City':
                tdFunc(
                    tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2], 
                    i,
                    filter
                );
                break;
            case 'State':
                tdFunc(
                    tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2], 
                    i,
                    filter
                );
                break;
            case 'Inspection Number':
                tdFunc(
                    tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[5], 
                    i,
                    filter
                );
                break;
        }
      });
    });
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

You can enhance it even more than this but here's just a quick example.

Comment: whats el here.
      Array.from(tr).forEach((el, i) => {

Comment: el in this case is a "tr" from the loop iteration. Get all the tr elements `var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");` which is an HTMLCollection. `Array.from(tr)` creates an iterable array from the HTMLCollection.